# .net C# zipArchive CreateEntryFromFile largesize will be OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, zip, out-of-memory

When I want to Compress the Large files (ex: an iso file about 2GB) using .net `System.IO.Compress`, It will show Exception and stop working.

It my Code:

```
 using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
            {
                zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"C:\test1.iso", "test1.iso", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
                zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"C:\test2.iso", "test2.iso", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
            }
```

Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

How can I do to slove this problem in x86 system? (in x64 it can run,but my app will be x86 app).

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585488/writing-to-ziparchive-using-the-httpcontext-outputstream

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `ZipArchive` class instead and the get or create a `ZipArchiveEntry` for each file. That has an `Open()` method that returns a `Stream` you can then write to. You may then have to read from the iso and write to the zip entry in smallish chunks (say, 64MB) to keep memory use down.

Note: I'm on the go so have not been able to test this; it's not impossible that this method will also crash, depending on the internals of ZipArchive.

Answer (score 0):

First Create List to Save item on Ziplist.
Sec.  ZipArchiveMode change use create.
Thir. foreach all item in Ziplist,to CreateEntryFromFile in saveZipPath.