# How to build a ZipArchive in memory and download through IHttpActionResult in Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API 2 `ApiController` with the following GET method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetZip()
{
    return new ZipFileActionResult();
}
```

My custom implementation of `IHttpActionResult`

```
public class ZipFileActionResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry("MyFileName.txt");

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write("It was the best of times, it was the worst of times...");
            }

        }

        response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "example.zip"
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

When I use Postman to GET, I get "No response". A breakpoint where `StreamContent` is created shows the stream to have a length around 1000 bytes. What have I missed?

### Other similar questions but not duplicates

This question is not a duplicate, although it appears to have some siblings:

- [ZipArchive creates invalid ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347775/ziparchive-creates-invalid-zip-file) but I'm not saving to windows so I don't have a file stream. I am also ensuring that the stream remains open after the `ZipArchive` as disposed.
- [Writing to ZipArchive using the HttpContext OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585488/writing-to-ziparchive-using-the-httpcontext-outputstream) but I am not writing straight out to the `HttpContext.OutputStream`, as I am streaming to `StreamContent`, I can use the simpler `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Should make any real difference whether you're writing to a MemoryStream or a FileStream.

Comment: You may need to reposition your memory stream to the beginning, using `memoryStream.Position = 0;`

Comment: @Frederico Dipuma - that was the correct answer. Please create a new answer with the full code so that I may up-vote it. The position reset must be applied after the ZipArchive `using` statement has completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must reset the `memoryStream` position to "0" so that it doesn't try to start from the end of the file when writing to the response. The fixed code should look like this:

```
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    var entry = archive.CreateEntry("MyFileName.txt");

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write("It was the best of times, it was the worst of times...");
    }
}

//ADD THIS LINE
memoryStream.Position = 0;    

response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
```