# ASP.NET Core Streaming directory content directly from disk

Tags: asp.net-core, stream, tar

I have a directory with a couple of files which I want to send to a client upon request. In order do this I have to somehow combine the files in a single file but I don't want to store this file (even temporarily) in a file system or entirely in memory. In other words I need to create an archive and stream it directly to the client.

A simple candidate for this seems to be a tarball. If I understand correctly a tarball doesn't contain a global file header but just a header for the individual files in the archive:
HeaderFile1-File1-glue-HeaderFile2-File2-finalizer

Assuming this is correct, it would be possible to generate a tarball without having to store it completely in memory or otherwise but I've looked into the libraries SharpCompress and SharpZipLib but neither seem to support something like this.

Before I try and implement it entirely myself two questions:

1. Is there an easier way to stream directory content to a client.
2. Does any commonly used library support the streaming of a tarball like I described?

FYI, I'm using ASP.net core 6

---

As an example using SharpCompress that first loads the tarball entirely in memory:

```cs
DirectoryInfo directoryOfFilesToBeTarred = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
FileInfo[] filesInDirectory = directoryOfFilesToBeTarred.GetFiles();
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
var options = new TarWriterOptions(SharpCompress.Common.CompressionType.None, finalizeArchiveOnClose: true)
{
    LeaveStreamOpen = true
};
using (TarWriter writer = new TarWriter(memStream, options: options))
{
    foreach (FileInfo fileToBeTarred in filesInDirectory)
    {
        writer.Write(fileToBeTarred.Name, fileToBeTarred);
    }
}
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return memStream;
```

Comment: This post may help you: [Writing to ZipArchive using the HttpContext OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585488/writing-to-ziparchive-using-the-httpcontext-outputstream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Chen I found a working solution with zip archives.

It seems obvious now, but the trick was to directly write to the response body's output stream.

```cs
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(Response.BodyWriter.AsStream(), // <--
                                           ZipArchiveMode.Create,
                                           leaveOpen: true))
{
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(path);
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(path, fname);
    }
}
```

And then return `new EmptyResult();` in the controller.

---

After some more tinkering the nicest way I found was to create a class derived from `ActionResult` and paste the above code in the overridden `ExecuteResult` method. The method has the `ActionContext` as argument from which you can get the response's `BodyWriter`.

In this case you can also easily set the response headers and works better in the asp.net pipeline.